# How to escape a subpath inside a url with Pyramid

Tags: python, url, routes, pyramid

I need to pass a subpath as a param in a route generated by Pyramid. I tried using urllib.encode and urllib.quote but get a "resource could not be found error" either way.

route generation:

```
mypath='a/b/c'
new_route = route_url('new_model_route', self.request, subpath=urllib.encode(mypath))
```

my route:

```
config.add_route('new_model_route', '/model/new/{subpath}')
```

generated url (with "resource not found error")

```
http://127.0.0.1:6544/rnd2/model/new/a%2Fb%2Fc
```

I know it has to do with the escaping because the url `http://blah/model/new/a` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route pattern `/model/new/{subpath}` would never match `/model/new/a/b/c` so I don't understand why you would be able to generate a URL for that pattern?

It is possible to pass the rest of the url as elements, however.

```
config.add_route('new_model_route', '/model/new/{subpath}')
request.route_url('new_model_route', 'b', 'c', subpath='a')
# /model/new/a/b/c
```

On the other hand, you have another option. You can create a new route to match these urls, such as:

```
config.add_route('new_model_route', '/model/new/*subpath')
# matches /model/new/a, /model/new/a/b, etc

request.route_url('new_model_route', subpath=('a', 'b', 'c'))
# /model/new/a/b/c
```

If you didn't actually want to match these URLs for some reason, you can add `static=True` to the `add_route` call, which means that you are only using the `route name` to generate urls but not to match them on incoming requests.

`subpath` and `traverse` happen to be special (this is all documented) but if you were hellbent on using 'a/b/c' you could use something else in the route pattern:

```
config.add_route('new_model_route', '/model/new/*rest')
# matches /model/new/a, /model/new/a/b, etc

request.route_url('new_model_route', rest='a/b/c')
# /model/new/a/b/c
```

Oh and since I'm on a roll, you can use the original approach with a simpler url which you may already have in your system.

```
config.add_route('new_model_route', '/model/new')
# matches /model/new only

request.route_url('new_model_route', 'a', 'b', 'c')
# /model/new/a/b/c
```

Comment: The /*rest method seems to do most of what I need but is there a way to have all of these parameters (a/b/c) be handled as a single string? Right now, I have to rejoin them in the new view.

Comment: Using the `*rest` syntax, Pyramid will always turn the remainder of that URL into a tuple. There are other attributes of the request object but they will be independent of the route matched, such as `request.path`. Doing what it sounds like, you're probably going to just have to do `rest='/'.join(request.matchdict['rest'])`.

Comment: So, I assume this would cause problems if I wanted to have other parameters passed in using the *rest syntax since I would have to tell what part of the tuple was the parameter and what part was the other stuff?

Comment: If the pattern is `*something` in Pyramid, then the `matchdict['something']` will be a tuple. What you pass into `request.route_url` is up to you. You can only have one of those `*` patterns in the route, and it must be the last pattern in the route.

Comment: You could have anything before that though. like `/model/{action}*rest` would match `/model/foo/bar/baz` with `matchdict` having `action='foo'` and `rest=('bar', 'baz')`.